# Simple Button problem In IE

Tags: html

I also discovered the button works with Firefox but not IE. Do you know why?

```
<td><a href="crt.php"><button>Create New Listing</button></a></td>
```

Comment: When you say doesn't work can you be more specific?  What's not working exactly?  What is supposed to be happening that isn't?

Answer (score 2):

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="location.replace('/crt.php')">Create New Listing</button></td>
```

I think this is more of what you're after.  I don't know if you can even use a button like you're trying to.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the reality of what actually works in browsers, according to the HTML5 spec you can't   have a `button` inside an `a`.

http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

> The `a` element
>   Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content
>   descendant.

http://developers.whatwg.org/content-models.html#interactive-content

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user
>   interaction.
>
> - `a`
> - `button`
> - ...

Comment: The reason that HTML 5 doesn't allow it is because it doesn't make sense and browsers are inconsistent in how they try to make sense from it. So it doesn't ignore reality at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a submit button?  That's actually an INPUT tag.  The FORM tag will make it go to the page you want.

```
<form action="crt.php" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Create New Listing" />
</form>
```

You could also use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

> Always specify the type attribute for the button. The default type for
>   Internet Explorer is "button", while in other browsers (and in the W3C
>   specification) it is "submit".

Comment: psst... apparently w3schools is [not being standards compliant and is refusing to listen to the w3c](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Thanks guys. Always educational on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <form action="crt.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Create New Listing">
    </form>
</td>
```